# The functionality requested a security token, but the project does not use any services that require a security token

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the Error Message I am getting:

"The functionality requested a security token, but the project does not use any services that require a security token."

I am not understand this Error message my web app is sending me.  I tried removing permission to Drive and then going through the approval process again to see if that would fix it, but it didn't.

My biggest question is what part of the functionality is requesting a security token and what exactly does that mean? Also, I thought that since I am just working inside Google app Script editor that I wouldn't need a security token to access other Google apps like docs, sheets etc...  So, I am a little confused by this error message.  I tried searching on Google, but couldn't find any thing to help explain this to me.

here is my code:
Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  DriveApp.getFolderById('0B6YzuBeNxooXSWE3Vm9WMlVnWkk');
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
  .setTitle('06 Automating Forms')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return html;

}
```

index.html:

```
<div class="body">
  <div><h2>This App will allow you to create a form from a template
  in Google Docs.</h2></div>
  <hr>

  <div id="options">
    <?var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B6YzuBeNxooXSWE3Vm9WMlVnWkk').getFiles();?>
    <select id='template'>
      <option value="notSel">Select a Template</option>
      <?while (files.hasNext()){
      var file = files.next();?>
      <option value="<?=file.getId()?>"><?=file.getName()?></option>
      <?}?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="form-content"></div>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
</script>

<style>
.body{
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried changing the src to:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: I just tried making that change, but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: I was able to get it to load on a folder from my drive. It loaded to the select a template screen. When does your error occur?

Comment: You are right, that fixed it.  I just didn't load the web app correctly.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why did that fix the issue?